# How can I add/remove select boxes from DOM when all select boxes have one name so that upon Submit I get value from active select box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, dom

TL;DR: I want to be able to make a selection using currently-active HTML `select` box, when I have multiple select boxes with the same name, but only one of them is to be active at any one time.

--

My question is this - I have multiple `filename` select boxes, that upon submit, always send the value of the last select box that is at the bottom of HTML that has `filename` name in HTTP Request. I want to find a way to send only the `filename` that is associated with the currently-active `a_XX_row` box, and not any others.

i.e. I select id of 40, I should only see the box that says "A-40 Designer and Specs", and not the 800 box.  When I press submit I want POST['filename'] to have the "A-40 Designer and Specs", but instead I always get the "A-800 Designer E.xlsm", because it is the last `select` in the HTML file.

```js
$('#modelid').on('change', function() {
    
    if (this.value == 40)
        $('.a_40_row').show();
    else
        $('.a_40_row').hide();

    if (this.value == 800)
        $('.a_800_row').show();
    else
        $('.a_800_row').hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form><table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="id" id="modelid">
        <option value="0">--select--
        <option value="40">40
          <option value="800">800
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="a_40_row" style="display: none;">
    <td>Version</td>
    <td>
      <select name="filename">
        <option selected>A-40 Designer and Specs B.xlsm</option>
        <option>A-40 Designer and Specs A.xlsm</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="a_800_row" style="display: none;">
    <td>Version</td>
    <td>
      <select name="filename">
        <option>A-800 Designer E.xlsm</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table></form>
```

Comment: On topic, don't hide and show different controls, populate the control with what you need. based on what you need. On a complete side note..... do not use the `table` tag for layouts.

Comment: ^ that will be an acceptable solution. .... For that I will need to pre-load all possible `filenames` and then dynamically load them upon selection I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options,

1. Enable/disable the element as you show it.
2. Populate one field with what you need.

**Option 1 :**

```js
$('#modelid').on('change', function() {
    //Set visibility
    $('.a_40_row').toggle(this.value == 40);
    //Toggle disabled
    $('.a_40_row [name=filename]').prop("disabled", this.value != 40);
    $('.a_800_row').toggle(this.value == 800)
    $('.a_800_row [name=filename]').prop("disabled", this.value != 800);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form><table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="id" id="modelid">
        <option value="0">--select--</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="800">800</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="a_40_row" style="display: none;">
    <td>Version</td>
    <td>
      <select name="filename" disabled>
        <option selected>A-40 Designer and Specs B.xlsm</option>
        <option>A-40 Designer and Specs A.xlsm</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="a_800_row" style="display: none;">
    <td>Version</td>
    <td>
      <select name="filename" disbled>
        <option>A-800 Designer E.xlsm</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table></form>
```

**Option 2 :** - This uses HTML 5 which has issues in IE 10 and less

```js
$('#modelid').on('change', function() {
   $(".row").show();
   var selVal = $(this).val();
   //Go through the options
   $("[name=filename] option").each(function(){
     //Dont use jquerys data here, it will convert to a number when it can
     //Get array of values where can display from the data attribute
     var arrDisplay = this.dataset.display.split(",");
     //Add the hidden property if not contained in array -- wont work in IE 10 and older
     $(this).prop("hidden", !arrDisplay.includes(selVal));
     //Set a default
     $(this).prop("selected", $(this).data("optiondefault") && !arrDisplay.includes(selVal) )
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form><table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="id" id="modelid">
        <option value="0">--select--</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="800">800</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row" style="display: none;">
    <td>Version</td>
    <td>
      <select name="filename">
        <option data-display="40" data-optiondefault="true">A-40 Designer and Specs B.xlsm</option>
        <option data-display="40">A-40 Designer and Specs A.xlsm</option>
        <option data-display="800" data-optiondefault="true">A-800 Designer E.xlsm</option>
        <option data-display="40,800">Hybrid</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table></form>
```

Answer (score 2):

don't show/hide selects form.

you just need to update the second select when the first is changed

the way to do that:

```js
const 
  myForm = document.forms['my-form']
, filenames = 
  [ { model:  '40', cod: 'A-40-B',  fn:'A-40 Designer and Specs B.xlsm' }
  , { model:  '40', cod: 'A-40-A',  fn:'A-40 Designer and Specs A.xlsm' }
  , { model: '800', cod: 'A-800-E', fn:'A-800 Designer E.xlsm'          }
  ]  

myForm.modelid.onchange = () =>
  {
  myForm.filename.innerHTML = ''
  filenames
    .filter(x=>x.model===myForm.modelid.value)
    .forEach( filename=>
      {
      myForm.filename.add( new Option(filename.fn,filename.cod))
      }
    )
  }
```

```css
select,
button {
  display : block;
  float   : left;
  clear   : left;
  margin  : .3em;
  }
select  {
  min-width : 8em;
  padding   : 0 .3em;
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <select name="modelid" >
    <option value="" selected disable >--select--</option>
    <option value="40"  >  40 </option>
    <option value="800" > 800 </option>
  </select>
 
  <select name="filename"></select>
 
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```